# Authentic, native word for a "hypergiant" in Hebrew?

Tags: hebrew

There is a blue hypergiant in my universe that is called "Kochav David". (yeah, I took it up literally). Thing is, the star functions like a planet, and people live there.

However, the "terrestrial" Hebrew word for hypergiant is "היפר-ענק" (hiper-anak), where the prefix is straight borrowed. The supergiant would be "על-ענק" (al-anak), so what hypergiant would be if it was a Hebrew word proper?

Comment: *Super* is the Latin translation of the Greek *hyper*; since they have the same meaning in their respective languages, so there is no way to differentiate the two by meaning other than by borrowing the words as they are (Hebrew translates the word in the case of the super- prefix but borrows the hyper- prefix). Since this is only a question about Hebrew I would think this is off-topic here as a language-specific question, but if you are thinking in terms of a hypothetical version of "authentic" Hebrew, you might be able to ask on [Constructed Languages](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks to @Draconis for answering :)                  I eventually came up with "tel-anak" (תל-ענק) for a "hypergiant", since "tel" in Tel-Aviv means "a mound of historic stuff placed on top of one another" or something close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Hyper" and "super" are actually cognates, and originally meant exactly the same thing in Ancient Greek and Latin. (`/s/` regularly turns into `/h/` at the beginning of a word before a vowel in Ancient Greek, and `/u/` turned into `/y/` over time.) In English, they generally mean exactly the same thing, and the choice of which one to use is arbitrary: see "hyper-active", which uses the Greek prefix on a Latin root.

In Hebrew, there's only one "native" prefix with this meaning, *ʕal-* (sometimes a suffix *-ʕal* as in *maħshabh-ʕal* "supercomputer" instead). So the easiest way to get another one is to do exactly what English did and borrow it from another language. That's where your *hiper-ʕanaq* comes from.

Another option would be to use the prefix and the suffix with different meanings: *ʕal-ʕanaq* "supergiant", *ʕanaq-ʕal* "hypergiant". But I don't know of any actual Hebrew terms that do this, and it's liable to cause confusion. Or you could use an entirely different prefix, like *rabh-* "many", but this feels like forcing a square peg into a round hole.